# How to evaluate $\int \sin^2 x \ dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

The fact that sin is squared is really throwing me off, can't seem to relate it to any standard integrals.

Comment: Do you mean $\int\sin^2 x\; dx$?

Comment: **Hint:** You may be aware of the following identity:
$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** Remember that $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$ and use the double angle formula.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$I=\int \sin^2(x)dx$$
and
$$J=\int \cos^2(x)dx$$

$$I+J=\int dx=x+C_1$$
$$J-I=\int \cos(2x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)+C_2$$

thus by substraction

$$I=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)+C$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\sin^2xdx\\=\int(1-\cos^2x)dx\\=\int dx-\int\cos^2x dx\\=x-\frac12\int(1+\cos2x)dx\\=x-\frac12x-\frac12\int\cos2x\ dx\\=\frac12x-\frac14\sin2x+C$$

Comment: $\cos^2x=\dfrac{1+\cos2x}{2}$

Comment: It is $1+\cos(2x)$

Comment: @Nosrati oops. Thanks.

Comment: @projectilemotion it's not my day :(